# Отличия между состоянием rebase и reset

Tags: git

Вопрос больше теоретический, чем практический, но любопытный, на понимание.

Если я сделаю `git rebase -i HEAD~10`, в каком-нибудь коммите, допустим третьем, поменяю pick на edit и остановлюсь на редактировании этого коммита, то чем это состояние отличается от состояния `git reset --hard HEAD~7`?

И там и там состояние detached head, однако они чем-то отличаются.

В первом случае `git status` выдаёт `interactive rebase in progress; onto...`, во втором — `your branch i behind origin\master by 3 commits and can be fast-forwarded`.

Чем же они отличаются с точки зрения git?

Comment: начав ребейз  или мердж, вы должны его завершить. А reset - уже свершился. Теоретически, если прибрать признаки ребейза и поправить указатели веток, то можно получить то же состояние, что и после reset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Технически эти состояния наличием папки `.git/rebase-merge`, а также несколькими дополнительными файлами в `.git` в зависимости от того на какой операции остановился rebase.

По смыслу эти состояния отличаются тем, что после reset у вас "чистое" состояние, а после 3х шагов rebase вы находитесь в состоянии "посреди rebase". При этом вам доступны некоторые дополнительные команды (например, `rebase --continue` или `rebase --abort`), но недоступны другие (`rebase`, `pull --rebase`).

Comment: Да, есть такие папки, не подумал, что это тоже может быть. Я смотрел на то, что в состоянии rebase master = origin\master, а HEAD != origin\HEAD, а при reset и master и HEAD указывают не на последние коммиты -- и думал, что в этом разница.